# why the input is different from what I gave to the compiler?

Tags: c, input, output

first of all, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   long int n;
   scanf("%ld",&n);
   int num=0;
   for(long int i=n;i!=0;i/=10) num++;
   int A[num];
   for(int i=num-1;0<=i;i--){
       A[i]=n%10;
       n=n/10;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
       printf("%d: ",A[i]);
       for(int j=A[i];j!=0;j--) printf("%d",A[i]);
       printf("\n");
   }
   
}
```

after the number gets too big after a certain point, the input is different from what i put in.
for example:

```
255678919916555247881
9: 999999999
2: 22
2: 22
3: 333
3: 333
7: 7777777
2: 22
0: 
3: 333
6: 666666
8: 88888888
5: 55555
4: 4444
7: 7777777
7: 7777777
5: 55555
8: 88888888
0: 
7: 7777777
```

my input is the number in the first line and the output is after that.
according to debugger variable n is different and that is what is giving me the output for.even for different inputs it is the exact same n and output.
where am i doing it wrong?
if there is any need for additional info please tell me.

Comment: You might read about ranges for different types in C. In many implementations, a `long` takes 4 bytes, i.e. 32 bits and your input is too large for your variables. For your implementation you might print `sizeof (long int)` or look at `LONG_INT_MAX` from `limits.h` header.

Comment: After looking at your output again, you seem to have 64 bit `long int` type where the limit is `9223372036854775807` which might look rather familiar... (But still not large enough for your input)

Comment: Do you need to do any calculations with that number? If not, use a string. Then you don't need any splitting of digits as you already have digits. Just remember that you need to subract `'0'` from each character to get the numerical value.

Comment: If you actually need to use numbers this large, you need to use a 3rd party "big int" library, since mainstream C applications only support up to 64 bit numbers, meaning the maximum value for a signed 64 will be `2^63 - 1`.

Comment: You would see the problem with a line like `printf("n=%ld\n", n);` after `scanf`. You should also check the return value of `scanf`. It returns the number of converted items, which should be 1 in your case. If it is not, you might see the uninitialized value of `n`

Comment: You are supposed to monitor your question and respond to comments/questions. Otherwise your post cannot be useful for any visitor